# How to make an input value permanent in wordpress or work with global variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, global-variables

I currently make my first Wordpress website using Java script snippets for a countdown that refreshes itself constantly and allows me to click a button once every 6 hours. So I managed that the time refreshes itself but I need one permanent variable that tells me if I already clicked the button or not (since it should work wether I refresh the page, go to another side or even log in with another user).
Basically I just want one variable that changes between 0 and 1.
I implemented a hidden input field and it works just fine as long as I stay on the side (refreshing the side works as well) but as soon as I change the page it sets the variable back. I tried to implement a global variable in the function.php of my theme (and a function as well) but it still doesn't work.

I tried it like this:

```
global $x;
echo $x;
```

And this:

```
function displayX() {
  global $x; 
  $x = "0";
  echo $x;
}
```

The thing is I don't want to set a value because the variable needs to be changeable any time.

That's my current html:

`<input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php echo $x; ?>" <="" input="">`

But it just doesn't work.

My second approach was to make the input field permanent (but updateable) - again this approach works as long as I don't change the side.
I tried it like this:

```
<span id="00">
<input type="text" id="id1">
        </span>
```

Can anybody please help me? Also please specifiy where I have to set the global variable since there are so many function.php files.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Permanent storage can't be done in a PHP variable. You need to use a database, a file or some sort of memory extension for the server where you would store this value. Is this something that you want to be different for each user or the same for all the users?

Comment: It should be the same for each user yes.

Comment: Then a simple textual file seems like a good choice.

Comment: Thank you!
Do you have any tutorial to do so? I don't really have an idea how to implement that. Can I simply "safe" the input or do I have to safe the variable differently (and not in an input field)?

Comment: You don't need an input on the page. The idea is this: you store whatever value you need in the file; in your script you read the file and calculate if the button should be enabled or disabled; your script that checks the time should update the file to allow clicking after your period has expired. You can start with the [simplest of tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp) and look for more info if you need further handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed the tutorial and was able to safe and update data in the text document. But I still have a problem getting the PHP "methods" in the Java Script snipet (and for example get the value of the PHP document in a JS variable). Is there any "trick" to do so?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer when your application structure is unknown. You might need AJAX, but I can't tell for sure. Can you rework the question to show your code and explain a bit more about how you're trying to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do that is using of **`update_option`** and **`get_option`**.
**`update_option`** is for save data to database that will be permanent.
**`get_option`** is for fetching data from database.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="permanent" id="permanent"  value="<?php echo get_option('permanent_data'); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

You can catch form data in backend using an action like this:
in functions.php

```
add_action('init','save_permanent');

function save_permanent(){
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        update_option('permanent_data', $_POST['permanent']);
    }
}
```

Below code checks that if form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    update_option('permanent_data', $_POST['permanent']);
}
```

If form submitted it gets value of input text that named **`permanent`**
Mentioned code permanent the data in database as name of **`permanent_data`**

If you want to fetch stored data you just call `get_option(option name)` like this:

```
<?php echo get_option('permanent_data'); ?>
```

For first question you can do it in such way:
in functions.php

```
<?php
if(if(isset($_POST['save']))){
    update_option('already_clicked', '1');
}
```

And for fetch stored data you can use:

```
<?php 
if(get_option('already_clicked') == '1'){
    //do somthing
}
?>
```